# Failed to start Windows after Ubuntu 11.10 install

Tags: windows, dual-boot, startup

Computer: HP Pavilion dv7-6140eo
OS: Originally Windows 7

I recently decided to try out Ubuntu, and I decided to dual-boot it with Windows 7. First I googled some how-to's, then I downloaded Ubuntu onto a memory stick and made a second partition (I originally only had one partition that I shrunk and used the unallocated space to install onto during the Ubuntu install). During the install I set format type to xt4 (or something, it was the default option), chose the "in the beginning" option and set the last option as "\".

The install was successful. Although, when I restarted my computer I weren't able to choose which operating system to start; it went right into Windows. After showing the Windows logo for half a second before rebooting, I get a blue screen (see bottom of the page). Trying to fix it, I deleted the newly made partition I had just installed Ubuntu onto (seeing it wasn't working either). This made no difference. I proceeded with installing Ubuntu again, so I would at least have a functioning computer, and now Ubuntu works fine (I'm on it now). The only difference on start-up is that I get a GRUB window asking me to between several options including Linux and Windows 7 (loader).

Now, if I choose Windows 7, I get the message: `Windows was unable to start. A recent software or hardware change might be the cause.`. It recommends me to choose the first option of the two it provides; to start start-up repair tool. The second option being starting Windows normally. If I start Windows normally, the same thing happens as earlier.

My computer does not have a Windows installation CD. Although, it has (at least it used to, if I haven't screwed that too up) a 17gb recovery partition. In addition I made an image of the computer onto a external hard drive when I first got it, though, I have no idea how to use either.

If anyone has any idea how I can make Windows work again or reinstall it (I already backed up my files) it would be greatly appreciated. I still prefer to dual boot between the two functioning operating systems, but I will settle for a functioning Windows 7.

**Blue screen:**

```
A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.

If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart your computer. 
If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check for viruses on your computer. Remove and newly installed hard drives or hard drive controllers. 
Check your hard drive to make sure it is properly configures and terminated. 
Run CMKDSK /F to check for hard drive corruption, and then restart your computer. 

Technical information:

**STOP: 0x0000007B (0xFFFFF880009A97E8,0xFFFFFFFFC0000034, 0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running Ubuntu from the live CD. Download the [Boot-Repair app](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) by choosing try Ubuntu and following the instructions of the linked page above. First try the recommended settings and see if it fixes your loading issues. IF not try the advanced options, or view the log that is generated by the boot-repair application.

Comment: Just ran the Boot Repair with the recommended settings, though it made no difference at all :/ 

Log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/878232/

Although, I did get this message after hitting recommended settings: "SFS detected. You may want to retry after converting Windows dynamic partitioning (SFS partitions) to a basic disk. This can be performed via tools such ad MiniTool Partition Wizard or EASEUS partition Master. Do you want to continue?" Don't know if it's significant in any way...

Comment: Try to manually place the boot-loader on sda2 or sda3. It appears you have 2 partitions installed with Windows7 (sda2, sda3), and Ubuntu on sda5. It also appears you have the boot-loader on sda0 which doesn't contain an OS.

Comment: Not really sure how to manually place it there, my computer skills aren't very advanced. I definetely can't do so with Boot Repair. Only gives me the choice of placing it (i.e. GRUB) into sda or to force it into sda5 (for chainloader).

I do only have one partition with windows 7 installed, either sda2 or sda3 it seems. One of them might have something to with the hidden recovery partition which, I forgot to mention, also is supposed to be bootable (to restore computer to factory settings), but no longer isn't.

Comment: When I try to boot from it I get the message "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible". And "Status: 0xc000000f" It seems when I installed Ubuntu I became unable to boot from any other partition.. Thank you for your continous help.

Comment: You can manually place it using the boot-repair app from the live cd. Click on the advanced options and you'll see it in the options.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the blue screen is the [BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death), which indicates that your system has suffered a critical error or it has collapsed.

This screen shows details about the error that has occurred and it is to prevent a damage to your software. I don't know exactly what to do, but if it is this case you can ask anyone on the internet or look for it in wikipedia, or microsoft's page.